# How can I duplicate Sass color functions in Sketch.app?

Tags: sass, hsl, sketch-3, hsb

Is there a way to use the equivalent of Sass color functions, like lighten and darken, to create color swatches in Sketch.app?

For example, original color #02284B

with Sass, I can use `darken(#02284B, 2%);` which will render as #022341

Is there an extension or technique for translating Sass color functions to the Sketch color settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [mfouquet/Darken-Lighten-Colors](https://github.com/mfouquet/Darken-Lighten-Colors). If that’s not powerful enough check out [CSSketch](https://github.com/JohnCoates/CSSketch).